# Tableau and Relational Databases

Tags: python, sqlite, tableau-api

I'm currently working on a project that using a program(python/r) to scrape data and send it to a relational database. Eventually, we will use tableau to do extra analytics and visualizations on the data.

At first, I was successful in using python to scrape and send to sqlite. However, it turns out that tableau doesn't carry sqlite and after doing some digging, it looks quite difficult to get tableau to accept sqlite data.

My question is thus, is there a simple explanation/way to get tableau to accept sqlite? If not, is there another relational database that would work well with both (python/tableau)? I've tried microsoft access but I don't think it pairs well with python.

Comment: There's a python package that will let you create Tableau TDE files. Maybe create the tde file directly instead of putting it into a database first. MariaDB is another option for a relational database that is easy to use and python plays nicely with it.

Comment: PostgreSQL works well